# Remove <li> elements that does not contain a certain "href" value inside <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have bought a wordpress theme called Salient : http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-frostwave/home-basic/

It has this AJAX search (little search icon in the menu) and I want to remove any search results from the list that has a certain href value, say "portfolio" in it.

I have tried with adding following code as a "raw html element" inside script tags in the page builder plugin but it did not work

```
$('a[href*="portfolio"]').css.({display:"none"})
```

How to I implement this on wordpress?

Update :

Thanks for all the answers. There was a "." after "css" and the correct line should be :

```
$('a[href*="portfolio"]').css({display:"none"})
```

Now I need to know how to select and hide all other elements that does not contain "portfolio". i.e. **the end result will only have the items with "portfolio" in it.**

I tried

```
href!="portfolio"
```

But it does not select any because != matches the exact and only "portfolio" where as my "portfolio can be **anywhere** in the link.

Comment: Guys thanks for the answers, how do I add this on wordpress?

Comment: The submitted answers are fine, but I wanted to just point out for future reference that your code should work if you just remove the period AFTER `.css`, so it would be `$('a[href*="portfolio"]').css({display:"none"});`...and don't forget your semicolons :)

Comment: @JonathanBowman thank you for pointing that out. Can't believe I missed that little dot.

Comment: After some research I came to know that it's a whole different thing to add custom jquery to Worpdress. Apparantly there is something called wp_enqueue_script to be used.
Thanks for all your answers. :)

Comment: Hi MaxE, you dublicate the same codes again :) clear "." on the second code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide all elements that does **NOT** contain the word portfolio:

```
$('a:not([href*="portfolio"])').css({display:"none"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need jQuery for this, add this to your `CSS` file:

`a[href*="portfolio"] { display: none }`

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNvrpG

Comment: Thank you! But the website search is more like AJAX. so the results don't get filtered.

Answer (score 1):

Why everybody write another code? There is a dot after css function, clear it. Replace with :

```
$('a[href*="portfolio"]').css({display:"none"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="portfolio"]').hide();
```

Comment: thank for the ansewer, but how do I add this on wordpress?

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="portfolio"]').closest('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have jquery, you can import it by adding this to HTML

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

So you can use your code `$('a[href*="portfolio"]').css.({display:"none"});`

Or you can use javascript (adapt as needed):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("yourId");
elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
```